# How to find checked radiobuttons in jQuery from a list of radiobuttons

Tags: jquery

In the below example I wish to select all the ":checked" radio buttons of the "radios" list. How to?

```
var radios = someDiv.find("input[type=radio]");
if (radios.length > 0)
{
    // I wish to find all the checked radio buttons in the
    // "radios" list - this doesn't work:
    var checkedRadios = radios.find(":checked");

    if (checkedRadios.length == 0)
        alert("You have to select an option stoopid");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your code work as it is, you just need to replace `find` by `filter`

```
var checkedRadios = radios.filter(":checked");
```

Unless you have any specific reason to make a 2 step selection, I'd recommend you to get selected radio buttons with one selector

```
var checkedRadios = someDiv.find("input[type=radio]:checked");
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I have to have the 2 step selection that's why I didn't just make it a one-liner. I didn't know about the filter function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if(someDiv.find("input[type=radio]:checked").length == 0)
  alert("You have to select an option stoopid");
```

if you know div id

```
if($('#someDivId').find("input[type=radio]:checked").length == 0)
      alert("You have to select an option stoopid");
```

if you know div class, but it will operate on all divs with this class

```
 if($('.someDivClass').find("input[type=radio]:checked").length == 0)
          alert("You have to select an option stoopid");
```

Comment: Yes, but then I would have to make the same selection again ("input[type=radio]"). I prefer working on the selection I've already made to avoid redundant code. The filter function that Claudio Redi mentions is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

`var radios = someDiv.find("input[type=radio]:checked");` should work

---

**Update**

```
var radios = someDiv.find("input[type=radio]");

// radios are there
if (radios.length > 0)
{
    var numChecked = 0;
    radios.each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) numChecked++;
    });

    if (numChecked == 0) 
        alert("You have to select an option stoopid");
}
```

Comment: I know, but I have to have that first check (line 2) to make sure some radio buttons exist. If no radio buttons exist I don't want to alert anything to the user.

Comment: No because if no checks are made that will return 0 even if there are radio buttons. The first check is to make sure there are radiobuttons to be selected

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to avoid a foreach though. The filter function makes for less code